# Remove excess samples/sound in a mp3 file

Tags: audio, sox

Ive been using SoX to trim files to be exactly 2 seconds long, but ive noticed that audio files always have an extra 32 milliseconds or so on the end, apparently its extra data to tell a different decoder its information, but does it have to add on to the length of the file?

I've created a program that joins together lots of files, 4 times (using "--combine") (Because there are 4 lines of music) then i join those four lines together using --combine mix
the length of the song is around 2:35 minutes long, but ive noticed, that the lines that got mixed start to go out of sync, like a time difference, im guessing that its the 37 milliseconds on the end of the file.

Can i fix this or remove the excess time? or maybe im just doing something wrong in my mixing, and that extra length doesn't get joint

Answer (score 2):

The issue is most likely with the MP3 format, which is chunked doesn't allow that kind of time resolution. Switching to another format, at least while you are editing, should resolve the issue.